# Find the expected number of purchases

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, expected-value

Suppose there are $a$ distinct kinds of badminton cards, each equally likely to be received with any given purchase, what is the expected number of purchases in order to acquire $b$ complete sets, i.e., at least $b$ of each of the $a$ types of cards$?$

---

This problem looks complicated to me. So I first considered the base case where $b=1$ it's quite simple and I got the answer as $$a\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1a\right)$$

---

But now the problem occurs. I can't figure out how to find the expected number of purchases for $b=2$ or $b=3$ as for me the case of general $b$ is too difficult.

---

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the [double dixie cup problem](https://faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Double-dixie-cup-problem.pdf), a generalization of coupon collector's problem.

Comment: Also, an interesting change in your profile name :)

Comment: I don't understand the question, and when I compute your formula with a=3, I obtain $\frac{11}2$ ; so, for $a=3$ and $b=1$,  the number of different puchases is $\frac{11}2$ ???